# Create policy with CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am able to create a policy this way with the AWS CLI:

```bash
aws iam create-policy --policy-name "alpha-policy" --policy-document file:///tmp/policy.json
```

The content of the `policy.json` is following:

```json
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     {
         "Sid": "Statement",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [ "s3:ListBucket"],
         "Resource": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

I convert it into the following CloudFormation file:

```yaml
 Resources:
     SimplePolicy:
       Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
       Properties:
            PolicyName: OfficialSimplePolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                 - Effect: Allow
                   Resource: "*"
                   Action:
                      - cloudformation:Describe*
```

And the command to create the policy with CloudFormation is:

```bash
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name bucket-policy --template-body file://BucketPolicy.yaml  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

When I run this command, I only get a stack ID back. However, no policy is created. What am I missing?

I would have expected the policy to be available in the aws console or via following command:

aws iam list-policies

It's nowhere to be found.

I checked the event list with:

```
 aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name bucket-policy
```

What this reveals is that: "At least one of [Groups,Roles,Users] must be non-empty."

And so my question is why can I create a policy without user, group or role when using the cli directly and I am not able to do the same when using cloudformation.

Comment: Why do you expect to get anything else back? Did you check the stack for the status and did you check IAM directly for the policy!?

Answer (score 1):

Following article explains my problem: https://cloudkatha.com/iam-policy-at-least-one-of-groupsrolesusers-must-be-non-empty/

Basically for standalone policies I should use ManagedPolicy. Also PolicyName is not a support field. These two changes solved my problem.